# Static sized combinations

Tags: permutation, set

Hour upon hour and I cannot come up with a solution.

Let's say I have ABC, I need all it's 3 letter combinations, abc, bbc, cbc etc. Not a ab abc etc. Can it be done with just loops? no recursion or methods?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (char ch1 = 'A'; ch1 <= 'C'; ch1++)
    for (char ch2 = 'A'; ch2 <= 'C'; ch2++)
       for (char ch3 = 'A'; ch3 <= 'C'; ch3++)
```

Comment: It will suck to implement it iteratively - use recursion:)

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to it with recursion? =)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281303/static-sized-permutations-from-dynamic-sized-set. The guy already gave you pseudocode. Show some effort on you side...