# Static sized permutations from Dynamic sized set

Tags: set, combinatorics

How can I obtain all combinations for a list where combination size need only be static eg. if the list has 4 elements then it will only need permutations of length 4 not 3, 2 and 1. I'm guessing this will need recursion. Unique combinations would be helpful but I'd like to see it in simplest (no uniqueness?) form for my puppy power.

Answer (score 0):

```
set s = { x1, x2, x3, x4 };
array solution;

permute( i ) =>
    if( i == 0 ) => print and return;

    while unused elements in set =>
        take element from set which is not in solution;
        put element in solution;
        permute( i - 1 );
        remove element from solution;
```

If you want a more specific answer you have to create a more specific question. Show some code/effort/whatever..